# Complexity classes and "local pre-processing"

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity, communication-complexity

**My question**

I have two complexity classes, $L$ and $Mod_kL$. I'm confident these classes satisfy $L\subsetneq Mod_kL$, as I'll explain below but you can take for granted for a moment. From these two classes I defined new classes, by allowing arbitrary processing of half the inputs for some fixed partition of the inputs. In particular,

$L_{(2)} \equiv \{f(x,y):f(x,y)=F(\alpha(x),\beta(y)), F\in L \}$

$Mod_kL_{(2)} \equiv \{f(x,y):f(x,y)=F(\alpha(x),\beta(y)), F\in Mod_kL \}$

Note that, somewhat awkwardly, $\alpha(x),\beta(y)$ could in general be longer than $|x|=|y|=n$, but by $F\in L$ I still mean that $F$ requires $\log n$ space, and similarly for $F\in Mod_k L$.

My question: is $L_{(2)} \subsetneq Mod_k L_{(2)}$? Or do these classes collapse under this sort "local pre-processing"? Any comments are appreciated, e.g. pointers to places in the literature where the power of this sort of pre-processing has been considered.

**Background on why I think $L\subsetneq Mod_kL$**

We know that $L \subseteq UL \subseteq Mod_k L$, see e.g. [1]

It's known that $UL/poly = NL/poly$, see [2]. Under the assumption that good pseudorandom functions exists, it has been shown this result can be improved to $NL=UL$, see [3].

It's generally believed that $L \subsetneq NL$. Combining this with the above two statements gives $L\subsetneq Mod_kL$.

**Citations:**

[1] "Structure and importance of log space-mod class" by Buntrock, Damm, Hertrampf and Meinel.

[2] "MAKING NONDETERMINISM UNAMBIGUOUS" by Reinhardt and Allender

[3] "Isolation, Matching, and Counting Uniform and Nonuniform Upper Bounds" by Reinhardt, Allender and Zhou

Comment: Questions like this go beyond our current knowledge of computational complexity.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you say that Yuval? E.g. is this related to some established problem that is thought to be hard to solve?

Comment: We don’t even know how to show that SAT cannot be solved in this fashion in polynomial time, even conditionally.

Comment: Okay I see, do you know of any references which discuss this kind of question about SAT (or any other problems)?

Comment: One possible starting point is Fortnow and Szegedy, On the power of two-local random reductions. You'll have to figure out on your own whether this is actually relevant, possibly digging in some of the references.